# How to update assmebly version info with new build and revision during build?

Tags: assemblyinfo, nant-task

I have to update the build number in assembly version of assemblyinfo.cs file.
I have written a custom tasks which updates all the assmeblyinfo.cs under a solution before starting build. But when i change this file and try to build then some of my dlls which has reference of other dlls not able to compile as they dont find the specific version assembly. I have some files which uses strong name assembly also. Not sure how to update their version. I have tried setting specific version to false,but still same error is coming.

Can you anybody tell me the good way to update the assemblyinfo.cs with incremental build number?

P.S. i am using NANT tasks for automating by builds.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good [NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) task called [Version](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/help/tasks/version.html) that should do what you're looking for